# javascript promise and catch

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

I am studying javascript promises. The first code works fine, but the second code gives an error.

When catching errors, isn't it sufficient for the reject function to be called? I don't understand the difference between using and not using the return statement in this context.

I expect not only first code but also second code work fine

```js
const f1 = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res("number1:complete")
    }, 2000)
  })
}

const f2 = (message) => {
  console.log(message)
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      rej("number2:fail")
    }, 3000)
  })
}

//first code >> success
f1()
  .then(a => {
    return f2(a)
  })
  .catch(console.log)
  
//second code >> error
f1()
  .then(a => {
    f2(a)
  })
  .catch(console.log)
```

Answer (score 2):

`reject` does make the related promise rejected, but that's it.

In your second example since you're not returning the promise it won't affect the resulting promise.

Your resulting promise from your `.then` is immediately resolved as it implicitly returns `undefined`.

`.catch` only applies to the promise object, which was resolved. It doesn't control anything about another promise that has been "detached" somewhere along the way.

Comment: This is correct - the promise is rejected, but because the `.then()` returns `undefined`, it doesn't have anything to pass on: see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#:~:text=The%20return%20value%20of%20each%20fulfilled%20promise%20in%20the%20chain%20is%20passed%20along%20to%20the%20next%20.then()%2C%20while%20the%20reason%20for%20rejection%20is%20passed%20along%20to%20the%20next%20rejection%2Dhandler%20function%20in%20the%20chain.).

Answer (score 1):

In the second code snippet, you are missing a return statement

```
then(a => { return f2(a) })
```

Comment: The OPs knows this, that's why they're asking the question: `When catching errors, isn't it sufficient for the reject function to be called? I don't understand the difference between using and not using the return statement in this context.`

Answer (score 1):

Without the `return` statement in this case, the `Promise` is never observed.  By returning a `Promise` here:

```
.then(a => {
  return f2(a)
})
```

that allows the chain of promise handlers (any additional calls to `.then()`, any call to `.catch()`) to observe the result of that `Promise`.  Without returning it, the call to `f2()` just goes unobserved because there is no `.then()` or `.catch()` attached to it.

---

A very common real-world example is calling `.json()` on the result of a `fetch()`:

```
fetch(someUrl)
  .then(result => {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // do something with data
  });
```

By *returning* the `Promise` from `result.json()` you can use that `Promise` in a follow-up `.then()` call in the overall chain.  Without returning it, there's nothing to follow-up on.